# Как изменить background-color в mat-accordion?

Tags: angular, accordion

Не mогу изменить цвет фона в акордеоне mat-Tabs.
В самой документации Ангуляра не нашёл ничего про изменение фона. И по стандарту фон белый

Вот пример

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <div class="IL">
          <img src="assets/Images/Bot2Icon54HW.png">
          <div class="Plashka FontLarge DirtyWhite">Cool Name</div>
          <div class="Plashka FontLarge DirtyWhite"> Bot ID</div>
        </div>
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смог найти как это поменять. Если кому это пригодиться то
нужно добавить любой клас к mat-expansion-panel-header и в класе описать bg-color
Также для отключения Hover можно использовать .disable_ripple:hover{background:currentColor !important;} добавив этот клас так-же к mat-expansion-panel-header